# Excel manipulation with python, no autocomplete in pydev and dir() is incomplete

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com

I tried this :

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispach
exc = EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = exc.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\testBook.xlsx")
ws = wb.Sheets('Sheet1')
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = "i'm writing"
```

And it's working, 
However pydev is not giving me anything in the autocomplete and 'dir(ws)' is returning a list of method and attributes but 'Cells' is not part of it.

Where could I find the list of all methods available on those object?

Thanks

Also, does anybody know the difference betwen EnsureDispatch and Client.Dispatch?

Comment: You need the Excel Object Model Reference, available from Help in Excel's VBA editor or here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068%28v=office.14%29.aspx. You need to use ws.Range("A1").Value

Comment: ws.Cells(1,1).Value is working, it's writing in A1

Comment: For example where would you find the information to translate this VBA line? Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Comment: OK, yes, the Excel object model is not easy to get started with, and the macro recorder could be more helpful. Range is the key object (Application.Selection returns a Range if a cell is selected). Here is the reference to Range.Insert as you demanded http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840310%28v=office.14%29.aspx. I don't generally buy books on programming, so I'm soory, I can't recommend one.

Comment: Well this link is excatly what I was looking for, thank you :D